# html5 semantic elements and old browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, semantic-markup

I am about to design a new layout for a webpage and wanted to take advantage of this moment to implement some html5 markup.

The first thing that comes in my mind are the semantic elements (nav, header, article..)

After checking http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic I noticed that IE8 (and below) don't support the elements.
This probably means that I cannot style the semantic elements expecting a coherent result.

The website receives quite a lot of traffic from IE7/8 browsers and I don't know how to proceed. 
I heard about modernizr and html5shiv but I don't know what's the best standard nowadays..

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer here (and on your other questions) if they solve(d) your problem. A low "accept" rate will eventually discourage users from answering your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're only looking for a method to style HTML5 elements, use HTML5Shiv (which is specifically designed for this purpose). Modernizr contains many more features. which you're not going to use (judging by the question).

Here's the source code, in case you're wondering: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js

Answer (score 3):

You can style them. You just have to run either the [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). You'd also want to add some CSS to make them block by default.

```
article, header, nav, section, footer
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to manually add the default styles when using HTML5Shiv or Modernizr, because they're already added (see [source code of HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js#L209), Modernizr [includes HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L998)).

Comment: @RobW Fair enough. I'm so used to doing it anyway I don't think about it anymore (it's in my reset.css file). Good catch, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make old versions of IE to recognize the new elements except via client-side scripting. If you decide that non-JavaScript use is ignorable, you can use some of the tools mentioned in other answers, or you can do yourself—the technique is odd, but not rocket science at all, e.g.

```
 <script>
 document.createElement('nav');
 document.createElement('header');
 document.createElement('article');
 </script>
```

A more robust solution is to use `div` markup with `class` (or `id`) attribute, in addition to using the new elements, e.g.

```
 <nav><div="nav">...</div></nav>
```

and to set your styles using class (or id) selectors like `.nav`. This would be robust, and it would also give you the benefits of using purportedly semantic markup like `nav`. (No tangible benefits have ever been presented, but maybe some will emerge.)

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should?) use them. Do make them display well in older browsers, I recommend the html5shiv.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

We used it here: [Midlands Health Network](http://provider.midlandshn.health.nz/)