# Need help making this work in IE8

Tags: html

Cant Seem to make this work in ie8
I just want my html5 to work but nothing seems to appear do i need to add more css?

```
 <!-- IE Conditional Comments -->


<!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('footer');
```

```
<style type="text/css">
menu, nav, footer { display:block; }
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667094/html5-semantic-elements-and-old-browsers

Comment: Try this: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: There's more that needs to happen than just putting in some CSS rules for supporting HTML5 elements in older browsers that were made before HTML5 (and hence won't recognize it). The html5shiv script linked by Supplement (mentioned in the answer to Matt Harrison's linked question) is the most popular way to have basic HTML5 support in browsers that do not recognize HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

[code.google.com/p/html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv)

Insert minified distribution shiv in  element (after or before your CSS):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope that helps.